# Calling SSRS Report Server it asked "Authentication Required" window

Tags: ssrs-2008, reportviewer, reporting-services, report-viewer2010

I have just started working in SSRS and I got a very strange problem i.e. When I am calling report server URL i.e. localhost/Reports

This URL requires Authentication window for Username and password. like this.
[image]

If I submitted local system user account information in that case it will appear me report server screen which we want. like this.
[image]

I have created a demo web-application and in the default.aspx page I am using `ReportViewer` to show report and configure it. here is the code which i am using
`Default.aspx` Page

```
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Width="100%">
</rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

`Default.aspx.cs` Page

```
    ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
    IReportServerCredentials irsc = new CustomReportCredentials("username", "password", "India");
    ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = irsc;
    ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://localhost/Reports");
    ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/SSRS_Demo/Report_CaseMain";
    ReportViewer1.ServerReport.Refresh();
```

`CustomReportCredentials.cs` Class

```
public class CustomReportCredentials : IReportServerCredentials
    {
        // local variable for network credential.
        private string _UserName;
        private string _PassWord;
        private string _DomainName;
        public CustomReportCredentials(string UserName, string PassWord, string DomainName)
        {
            _UserName = UserName;
            _PassWord = PassWord;
            _DomainName = DomainName;
        }
        public WindowsIdentity ImpersonationUser
        {
            get
            {
                return null;  // not use ImpersonationUser
            }
        }
        public ICredentials NetworkCredentials
        {
            get
            {
                // use NetworkCredentials
                return new NetworkCredential(_UserName, _PassWord, _DomainName);
            }
        }
        public bool GetFormsCredentials(out Cookie authCookie, out string user, out string password, out string authority)
        {
            // not use FormsCredentials unless you have implements a custom autentication.
            authCookie = null;
            user = password = authority = null;
            return false;
        }
    }
```

And while i am running this web-application in that case it will gives me an error i.e. 
[image]

Please help me out what will I do to resolve these all errors.....

Comment: you should probably remove your second error from this post and create a new question for it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After very long R&D I got a solution. I am using wrong SSRS service URL. I am using `localhost/Reports` but actually the SSRS Reporting Server URL is `localhost/ReportServer`. So by using this new Reporting Service URL i got the solution of that problem.

Answer (score 1):

Click on your report on localhost/Reports then goto property of that report. On right hand side there is '**Data Source**' click on that. Then chek the radio button '**Credentials stored securely in the report server**', here you need to specify your SQL server credentials i.e. User name and password

Answer (score 0):

One Time Activity: Once you click on report it will ask again the username and password first time, to overcome this follow below guidelines.

(i) Open Internet Explorer go to Setting click on Internet options

(ii)    Go to Security :-> Local Intranet -> Click on Sites

(iii)   Click Advanced:

(iv)    Add Site: ServerIP Addr (ex.172.16.2.224 or localhost) and then Close.