# How to disable the window integrated security while rendering the SSRS reports which are deployed on the remote server

Tags: sql-server, windows, user-interface, reporting-services

I have deployed SSRS Reports on the remote server and when I was trying to access the reports on the UI it was popping up with windows integrated security, How to disable windows integrated security while rendering the SSRS Reports?[image]

Comment: Same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11465530/calling-ssrs-report-server-it-asked-authentication-required-window

Comment: Does it prompt in IE as well?

Comment: yes, it is promoting for all Internet browsers.