# SSRS using SP with option(recompile) still taking forever to load report embedded in asp.net ReportViewer

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, reporting-services, reportviewer

I have a SSRS report.

When I open the report using SSRS browser page at http://localhost/reportserver the report works fine and loading data. Data is just 4 rows.

But when I embed the report in report Viewer, it takes forever to load means never loads just progress status showing.

I have added `option(recompile)` but still no result.

Following is my SP

```
 BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

select s.Name,s.Id as STUDENT_ID,a.AttendanceStatus,a.AttendanceDate,

  case when (select count(*) from
  Attendance where AttendanceStatus='Present')>
                           (select count(*) from Attendance where 
     AttendanceStatus='Absent') then 'Regular' else 'Not Regular' end as IsRegular
  from Student s 
  inner join Attendance a on s.Id=a.Student_ID
  where s.Id=@Student_Id

  option(recompile)
```

END

Following is my C# code that I used to get report in reportViewer

```
    ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new System.Uri("http://localhost/ReportServer");
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/Report1";
        ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;


        Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter[] Param = new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter[1];
        Param[0] = new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter("Student_Id","1");



        ReportViewer1.ShowParameterPrompts = false;
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(Param);
```

Comment: In absence of other details (execution plan and index information), I would ask you to try fix for parameter sniffing. Can you try declaring `@Student_Id_loc` and assign it with `@Student_Id` and use `@Student_Id_loc` in your query. Remove `option(recompile)`

Comment: also you can look into `executionlog3` table in reporting server and check where does it take time. You have `TimeDataRetrieval`, `TimeProcessing` and `TimeRendering` columns which will tell you what needs fixing.

Comment: These timings are for the execution of your report from ReportViewer in your application? If yes, then looks like report executed fine. May be some other issue within your application.

Comment: @AB_87 sorry I deleted the comment. There is no row in log for the report means report is not hitting. My report is on my desktop and I am giving reportpath as "/Report1.rdl" my reporting server is in native mode. any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: I may be wrong but I don't think you can run rdl report like that from your desktop. As you mentioned you can already deployed it to your local server so you can execute it from localhost server. May be with code something similar to below post. You can also provide your c# code in your question and I am sure experts will be able to help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11465530/calling-ssrs-report-server-it-asked-authentication-required-window

Comment: Are you running the report in VS? VS can cache your data so you are not always getting the latest unless you refresh the data.

Comment: @RossBush to clear cache should I clean the project? should it delete the cache?

Comment: Just a refresh of the data source should clear the data files. In your project, you just need to click the green swirly.

Comment: @RossBush you mean blue swirly

Comment: @AB_87 I have updated my question with `C#` code. Please check. There is nothing wrong.

Comment: @Alex I hope, this is code on some button click action. Apart from missing `ReportServerCredentials` code looks OK, but if you can see report loading, access shouldn't be an issue. I tested with my local report and worked fine for me.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know any logic behind it but i had the same problem, declare a new variable in your SP and put the value of "@Student_Id" in it at first, then use this new variable in your queries

hope it works for you too